# AOS animation on click event?

Tags: jquery, css, plugins, jquery-plugins, css-transitions

My page is using AOS plugin for animation. AOS will load with the page load:

```js
AOS.init({
  once: true,
  easing: 'ease-in-out'
});
```

Navigation list on the same page is hidden. It should display only when we click on the nav menu icon (hamburger icon). I want the list also to be animated using AOS plugin.

This is the code I am using to initialise plugin on click:

```js
var iconButton = $("button");
iconButton.on("click", function() {
  AOS.init({
    startEvent: 'click',
    easing: 'ease-in-out'
  });
});
```

But, I think this plugin will initialise when the page is loaded. Any idea, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 6):

```
AOS.init({
    once: true,
    easing: 'ease-in-out'
});
var iconButton = $("button");
iconButton.on("click", function() {
    $(iconButton).removeClass('aos-animate');
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(iconButton).addClass('aos-animate');
    }, 400);
});
```

[jsfiddle Test](https://jsfiddle.net/yo41587u/)

Comment: Great solution. How would you use this method on items that were hidden and will just be scrolled into view?